# Access entire gsuite domain calendar events

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-workspace, service-accounts

I want to access the entire events existing in a calendar of a gsuite domain. I tried using domain deligation with service account and it allows me to assume a user and get all of its events but i want to fetch the entire events in a gsuite account.

Comment: Grant that user access to everyone elses accounts.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "i want to fetch the entire events in a gsuite account"? Do you mean all the events from all the users in the domain?

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I want. So I have a scenario where I would like to fetch all the events from all the users calendar and add some more details to the events and I don't want to assume role for each user get their calendar events. I want just the permission to access all the calendar events of users let's say existing in the gsuite.

Comment: @DalmTo can you please elaborate. I am not too much familiar with passing permission in any other way using similar method what I have tried is take the clientid of service account and added permission to access calendar and directory resource calendar from the admin console of gsuite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In order to achieve your task, you should create a service account which impersonates the admin of the domain.**

Afterwards, you can retrieve the users of the domain by making use of the Admin SDK.

```
GET https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users
```

Based on the list you get, you can get the events from the calendar of each user.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events
```

Where, `calendarId` is the email of one of the users from the domain.

#### Reference

- [Admin SDK users.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list);
- [Calendar API events.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list).

Comment: it will be a hassle to handle when the users count is massive. thanks though i will accept the answer i was opting for get all activity and filter from there i will give this one a shot. cool.